# Count rows belonging together

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to create a Procedure filling in discount values on higher shipping amounts.

In my Table there are all article numbers, the amount of orders needed for the discount and the discount.

I want to have the article number + a counting value of the amount of orders needed just for the CASE WHEN in my update.

Right now I only get the rownumber of the complete select:

```
IB-000074   53
IB-000074   8487
IB-000074   8592
IB-000075   8593
IB-000075   54
IB-000075   8486
```

I need to display something like this:

```
IB-000074   1
IB-000074   2
IB-000074   3
IB-000075   1
IB-000075   2
IB-000075   3
```

Anyone knows how to replace the lowest value with 1, the 2nd lowest with 2 and so on?

Comment: you could use `row_number()over(partition by ID order by something) as rn`

Comment: Oh god I love you! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi You should post that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer Link: [Row_number()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Refer Link: [Over clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

You could use

```
row_number()over(partition by ID order by something)
```

Refer Link: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808324/row-number-over)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ordering function, like

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AMOUNT)
```