# Duplicate rows in view and give each duplicate a new ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I am confronted with a hopefully easy to solve Problem:

Currently my view looks like this:

| Credittype | Person |
| --- | --- |
| Type 1 | James |
| Type 2 | Jose |
| Type 2 | Mike |

Now I want to duplicate each row in this example 2 times, and give each copied row a new number.

The resulting table should look like this:

| Credittype | Person | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Type 1 | James | 1 |
| Type 1 | James | 2 |
| Type 1 | James | 3 |
| Type 2 | Jose | 1 |
| Type 2 | Jose | 2 |
| Type 2 | Jose | 3 |
| Type 2 | Mike | 1 |
| Type 2 | Mike | 2 |
| Type 2 | Mike | 3 |

An easy solution would be something like:

```
Select Credittype, Person, "1" AS Number from table 
union all
Select Credittype, Person, "2" AS Number from table 
union all
Select Credittype, Person, "3" AS Number from table
```

The problem is that in reality I need to copy those rows 50 times... I think there is a more efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count rows belonging together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325662/count-rows-belonging-together)

Comment: the answer will depend on database system you use (mySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL ...)

Comment: I use microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to `CROSS JOIN` to cause the duplication and derived numbers...

```
SELECT
  src.Credittype,
  src.Person,
  num.Number
FROM
  table      src
CROSS JOIN
(
            SELECT 1 AS Number
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS Number
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS Number
)
  num
```

Or, with SQL Server...

```
SELECT
  src.Credittype,
  src.Person,
  num.Number
FROM
  table      src
CROSS JOIN
(
  VALUES (1), (2), (3)
)
  num(Number)
```

There are also numerous answers on SO which show ways of generating tables *(or inline-views)* of large ranges of numbers.  Such as...

- [How to generate a range of numbers between two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
Declare @creditTypes Table (CreditType varchar(10), Person varchar(100));
 Insert Into @creditTypes (CreditType, Person)
 Values ('type 1', 'James')
      , ('Type 2', 'Jose')
      , ('Type 2', 'Mike');

   With t(n)
     As (
 Select t.n
   From (Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) As t(n)             
        )
      , iTally (Number)
     As (        
 Select Top (50)
        checksum(row_number() over(Order By @@spid))
   From t t1, t t2              -- 100 rows
        )
 Select *
   From @creditTypes                    ct
  Cross Apply iTally                    it
  Order By
        Person
      , Number;
```